# defaults.setValue save value always nil string

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, nsuserdefaults, remember-me

I am trying to create remember me functionality and for that i have to use NSUserDefaults to save data in cache. But it always save nil string kindly check my code.

```
struct defaultsKeys {
    static let email = ""
    static let pass = ""
    static let remember = "0"
}

@IBAction func btn_rememberMe(sender: UIButton) {

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        if defaults.stringForKey(defaultsKeys.remember) == "0" {
            defaults.setValue("1", forKey: defaultsKeys.remember)
            btno_rememberMe.setImage(UIImage(named: "login_tickSelected.png"), forState: .Normal)
        }
        else {
            defaults.setValue("0", forKey: defaultsKeys.remember)
            btno_rememberMe.setImage(UIImage(named: "login_tickUnselected.png"), forState: .Normal)
        }
    defaults.synchronize()
}
```

Code to Save Email and Password:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
                if defaults.stringForKey(defaultsKeys.remember) == "1" {

                    defaults.setValue(String(self.txt_email.text!), forKey: defaultsKeys.email)
                    defaults.setValue(String(self.txt_pass.text!), forKey: defaultsKeys.pass)

                    print(defaults.stringForKey(defaultsKeys.email)!)
                    print(txt_email.text!)
                }
                else {
                    defaults.setValue("", forKey: defaultsKeys.email)
                    defaults.setValue("", forKey: defaultsKeys.pass)
                }
                defaults.synchronize()
```

Code to Reload data on screen:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if defaults.stringForKey(defaultsKeys.remember) == "0" {
        btno_rememberMe.setImage(UIImage(named: "login_tickUnselected.png"), forState: .Normal)
    }
    else {
        btno_rememberMe.setImage(UIImage(named: "login_tickSelected.png"), forState: .Normal)
        txt_email.text = defaults.stringForKey(defaultsKeys.email)
        txt_pass.text = defaults.stringForKey(defaultsKeys.pass)
    }
    defaults.synchronize()


}
```

It saving remember value but not email and password.

Comment: Because you use *empty strings* as keys for email and password.

Comment: No i am adding text to textfield and i have also printed it and textfield text is not empty

Comment: Yes: `defaultsKeys.email` is defined as the empty string. Therefore the *key* for the user defaults is an empty string (not the value).

Comment: @MartinR in a Structure?

Comment: My last attempt: You have defined `static let email = ""` , therefore `defaultsKeys.email` is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Here in the Structure

```
struct defaultsKeys {
    static let email = ""
    static let pass = ""
    static let remember = "0"
}
```

you have defined `email` and `pass` as Blank and for `remember` you have assigned it to 0, thats why for `remember` it is storing the value and not for the other values.

To solve it just change the structure as below

```
struct defaultsKeys {
    static let email = "savedEmailKey"
    static let pass = "savedPassKey"
    static let remember = "0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `defaultKeys` structure is used to store the *keys* of `NSUserDefaults`. Am I right? And is empty string a valid key? No.

I think you just mixed up the keys and values for the defaults. Just change the keys to something meaningful:

```
struct defaultsKeys {
    static let email = "email"
    static let pass = "pass"
    static let remember = "remember"
}
```

Also, here's another suggestion.

Since `remember` can only be 0 or 1, you shouldn't save it as a `String`. Why not use a `Bool` instead? Just use `setBool` and `boolForKey` instead of `setString` and `stringForKey`!